# Read Rabbit MQ SSL server certificate and server key by Trust Store Plugin

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, self-signed

I am using SSL self signed certificates to connect MQTT in rabbit MQ broker. Now I need to update them runtime without restarting server. Rabbit MQ trust store gives good solutions for this, but it read only CA certificate from local whitelisted folder or http endpoint. I need to take server certificate and server key from external whitelisted folder or http endpoint. Can I do this using rabbitmq-trust-store plugin or else have any other solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

No need to restart server. Put the new certificate in correct place and wait for a few minutes. Certificates automatically update.